# Pentaho files browse panel folders are hidden

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, file-browser, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

Hope you people are fine, I have been working in PENTAHO and have made a dashboard successfully, but when i have uploaded my files and folders on the server,  cde, cda file are rendering in the file browser panel, but Folders don't appear for my images, css and js. dashboard is working perfectly as folders are there, i checked it by making folders with the same name and it said folders already exists, but they are not visible, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278375/uploaded-files-are-hidden-in-pentaho/33278376#33278376

Comment: Lolz i have already fixed it, its an old post of mine, anyways thanks for yoru help. @RIzanZaky

Comment: :) anyway some others would find it handy (Y)

Comment: @RIzanZaky ohh yes...

Answer (score 4):

Go to the "Browse Files" in Pentaho. Then on the menu, click 'view > show hidden files'
[image]