# Uploaded files are hidden in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I uploaded a zip file to the Pentaho public folder. But only the folder structure is shown, all files are hidden and the folder is stated as empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the "Browse Files" in Pentaho. Then on the menu, click 'view > show hidden files'

Comment: Thank you . I also , find some answer to same reason.